# SQL: copy data from one table to another while adding additional columns of fixed values

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to copy two columns from table 1 into table 2, filling another two columns in table 2 with fixed strings. Here's what I've attempted:

```
table1 has columns: name, age, child, adult
table2 has columns: name, param, xvalue, yvalue

INSERT INTO table2 (name, param, xvalue, yvalue) 
  VALUES ('John', 'age', 
      SELECT child FROM table1 WHERE name='John',
      SELECT adult FROM table1 WHERE name='John');
```

But it gives a `missing expression` error.

The result should have table2 `name` column be `John` for all rows, and likewise the `param` column should be `age` for all rows. Table 2 `xvalue` and `yvalue` columns should contain the selected data from table 1.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (name, param, xvalue, yvalue) 
     SELECT 'John', 'age', child, adult
     FROM table1 
     WHERE name = 'John';
```